# Export default const with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I have this in a TS file:

```
exports.default = module.exports;
```

(This is to support both Node style and TS style imports.)

Is there a way to create the above line of code with pure TS instead of JS?

I tried this:

```
export default const = module.exports;
```

and that does not transpile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat counterintuitively, the answer appears to be:

```
export default module.exports;
```

that's it.

however, in order to get any .d.ts files to behave correctly, you actually are best off doing this:

```
let $exports = module.exports;
export default $exports;
```

you can read about this here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16442